# Create DataAnnotations in runtime from own metadata system

Tags: .net, data-annotations

For example I store information about display column in database and I don't want to use DisplayColumnAttribute for define this. What can I do to create DataAnnotations info in runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to use "DynamicData Buddy Classes" feature. It allows holding validation metadata in a separate class. So you can create your custom generator that will generate that "buddy classes" from your database.

**Update:** Check [this blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/marcinon/archive/2008/05/22/dynamic-data-samples-custom-metadata-providers.aspx) i found today when encountered yet another limitation of DataAnnotations attributes mechanism.